# Replace the tab close confirmation box with own customize modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to replace the popup of the browser when we click the close button of the tab.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
    debugger
    event.preventDefault();
    if (JSON.parse(getItemSession('stepperDataChanged'))) {
        event.returnValue = ''
        setShowXMLDownloadPopUp(true)
        //here I am trying to show my popup only
    }
    console.log("data", event)
    setItemSession('stepperDataChanged', true)
    
});
```

[image]